# svelte/PHP Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: php, mysql, svelte

I went through all related questions (with Unexpected end of JSON input) and I have not found any solution yet.

Basically I have a MySQL view and PHP file that displays these data. Until there were just sample data (around 50k rows) I had no problem at all, just a slight delay. Now I added more complete dataset (around 90k rows) and I encounter a delay on full data load. Respectively when I open that PHP in browser, it loads just a part of data and continuously keeps appending rest until it shows all. But it seems that await svelte cannot cope with that.

This is the PHP code, stripped from non-relevant features:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');

require_once(__DIR__.'/protected/config.php'); //initial setting

try{
    $q = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM my_view;'); //this is that view in MySQL
    $q->execute();
    $rows = $q->fetchAll();
    echo json_encode($rows);
    exit();
}catch(PDOException $ex){
    err('error executing query', __LINE__);
};
?>
```

The size of underlying data for the view is around 9Mb. (5Mb were fine)

And here is the svelte code again without non-relevant features:

```
<script>
import Chart from "Chart.svelte";
let ready;
let data = loadDataUrl('http://127.0.0.1/myfile.php');

async function loadDataUrl(address) {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(address);
        const text = await res.json(); //here might be the ERROR arising

        if (res.ok && text) {
            ready = true;
            return text;
        } else {
            throw new Error(text);
        }
    } catch(ex) {
        alert(ex);
    };
};
</script>

{#await data}
    <p>...loading data...</p>
{:then ready}
    <Chart data="{data}" />
{:catch error}
    <p style="color: red">Chart not created because of: {error.message}</p>
{/await}
```

I am pretty sure the problem arises, when PHP shows just partial data and the function loadDataUrl() tries to parse this inclomplete dataset, but I totally have no clue how to do an "await for full data load". Is this even possible? Or do I need to say it somehow in the PHP itself to show complete dataset?

Answer (score 0):

I think I hit some MySQL/PHP pipe limit... (please correct me, if I am talking non-sense). I have not found any proof for this and my limited knowledge does not allow me find more detailed information.
For this large volume data, I decided to stick with local JSON files fetch:

```
let data = loadDataJson('assets/myfile.json');

async function loadDataJson(location) {
    try {
        const res = await fetch(location);
        const text = await res.json(); 

        if (res.ok && text) {
            ready = true;
            return text;
        } else {
            throw new Error(text);
        }
    } catch(ex) {
        alert(ex);
    };
};
```

This works fine even for bigger datasets (up to 50Mb JSON files tested), but I will be more than glad if someone could contribute on this problem and help others solve similar problems.